# Yosemite Photos: How to select only photos

Tags: photos

Photos Version 1.0.1 (215.65.0)
I can't seem to see anywhere inside Photos to filter items by file type.  No detail/list view like in Finder for me to sort and select. Search with, for example `*.JPG` in the search box of Photos does not return anything. It does not seem to understand wildcards

Comment: So, do you want to _filter_ or _sort_? Reason I ask is that the Photo's app supports **Smart Albums** but these filter based on criteria.

Comment: @bjbk I usually sort by file type and then select the files of the same type (i.e. JPG). So I guess both filter and sort, but the net effect is filter

Comment: See my updated answer regarding using the Search field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you can create **Smart Albums**

These can be set to filter based on filetype.  You can set as many of these as you wish, and even modify existing ones.

In **Photos** go to **File > New Smart Album** or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Then you can set your filter criteria in several ways.  See the attached screenshot illustrating a PNG filter.

[image: Photos filter by filetype]

**UPDATE:** If you choose to use the Search field, enter just "jpg" without quotes to get a dropdown that shows filetype.

[image: jpg search]

Comment: I overlooked the `Smart Album` for this purpose.

Comment: This method dynamically updates as well. Not a quick solution, but can really help to narrow things down.

Comment: I think the interface is misleading: On the sidebar, there are: Photos, All Photos, Faces, Last Import, and Videos. I can select all videos by clicking "Videos" so I expect "Photos" gives me only photos.

Comment: Those are built in smart folders.  Yeah, takes time to wrap our heads around new interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the update about search box. Seriously, you have 10k photos in Photos :)

Comment: Those are just the jpgs.  Lots of history in there. ;-)